# Angular service with add/delete items using observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm working on a service. It has an Observable that is used to emit the product lines of an order.

The stream with intial order lines (it maybe empty)

```
linesOrder$: Observable<Line[]|any> = this.orderService.selectedOrder.pipe(
share(),
map(
  (order: Order) => {
    if (!order.lines) {
      return of([])
    }
    return order.lines || of()
  }
),
tap(data => console.log('data ', JSON.stringify(data)))
);
```

Then, I'm trying to respond when a new line is added or deleted, using stream actions:

```
//  Insert Action stream
  private lineInsertedSubject = new Subject<Line>();
  lineInsertedAction$ = this.lineInsertedSubject.asObservable();
  linesWithAdd$ = merge(
      this.linesOrder$,
      this.lineInsertedAction$
  ).pipe(...);

 addLine(newLine?: Line) {
   this.lineInsertedSubject.next(newLine)
 }
```

same for deleting a line:

```
//  Delete Action stream
  private lineDeletedSubject = new Subject<Line>();
  lineDeletedAction$ = this.lineDeletedSubject.asObservable();
  linesWithDelete$: Observable<Line[]> = merge(
    this.linesOrder$,
    this.lineDeletedAction$
  ).pipe(...)

  deleteLine(line: Line) {
    console.info('eliminar linea');
    this.lineDeletedSubject.next(line);
  }
```

The thing is I'm very confused because what I want is to emit a stream of Line[] when

- I received the intial order lines
- When a line is added
- when a line is deleted

so, I created this in the service:

```
updatedLines$ = merge(
    this.linesOrder$,
    this.linesWithAdd$,
    this.linesWithDelete$
  )
  .pipe(
    tap(data => console.log('updated'))
  );
```

this updatedLines is used in component like this:

```
lines$ = this.lineService.updatedLines$;
```

then in template:

```
<div *ngIf="lines$ | async as lines">
  <p class="text-info">Selected lines: {{ lines.length }}</p>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let line of lines">
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-subtitle>{{ line.item_code }}</ion-card-subtitle>
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label class="label">Quantity</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="number" step=".1" (keypress)="numberOnlyValidation($event)" value="{{ line.quantity }}"></ion-input>
        <ion-button color="primary" (click)="onDelete(line)">remove</ion-button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</div>
```

I'm not able to get updated data in template, when I add a line, it reaches the method addLine() but updatedLines$ is not emitting. Same with deleteLine().

Firstly I tried with combineLatest but found that only will emit when 3 streams emit, I need to emit value if any of the 3 streams emits.

Comment: “ map(
  (order: Order) => {
    if (!order.lines) {
      return of([])
    }
    return order.lines || of()
  }
),” - this map sometimes returns an observable and sometimes doesn’t. That might cause issues.

Comment: how should I ensure that is returning always an observable? It can happen that current order has no lines, so I should return an empty observable?

Comment: The service is already observable, so I guess you do not need to map to of(). You either have orderlines or else an empty array [].. not sure if this is related to your issue though, just thought it didn’t look right..

Comment: When you add a line, do you want all lines + the new line displayed in the template, or just the new line?

Comment: I want all lines + the new line displayed in the template, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need a `scan`?

If you could provide a stackblitz with your problematic bit of your code, I could provide detail with your example.

Without that, here is my code that has a similar purpose:

```
  productsWithCRUD$ = merge(
    this.productsWithCategory$,
    this.productModifiedAction$
  )
    .pipe(
      scan((products: Product[], product: Product) => this.modifyProducts(products, product)),
      shareReplay(1)
    );
```

Just like you, I use a merge to merge my original data stream with the action, but I use one action instead of separate actions. Each time there is a modification action (create, update, delete), it uses `scan` to adjust the array and re-emit it.

The `modifyProducts` method looks like this:

```
  // Modify the array of products
  modifyProducts(products: Product[], product: Product): Product[] {
    if (product.status === StatusCode.Added) {
      // Return a new array from the array of products + new product
      return [
        ...products,
        { ...product, status: StatusCode.Unchanged }
      ];
    }
    if (product.status === StatusCode.Deleted) {
      // Filter out the deleted product
      return products.filter(p => p.id !== product.id);
    }
    if (product.status === StatusCode.Updated) {
      // Return a new array with the updated product replaced
      return products.map(p => p.id === product.id ?
        { ...product, status: StatusCode.Unchanged } : p);
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps.

You can find the complete code here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-RxJS

It's in the APM-WithExtras folder in the product.service.ts file.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned a solid way to handle state over time in `rxjs` is to use [scan](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/scan). There is a solid, maintainable way to use this operator in a very structured, maintainable and debuggable way:

```js
const { Subject, of, merge } = rxjs;
const { scan, map } = rxjs.operators;

// observable sources
const initialValue$ = of([1, 2, 3]); // simulates linesOrder$
const add$ = new Subject(); // subject to add a line
const delete$ = new Subject(); // subject to delete a line

/*
update functions that are used to update the state (lines)
- functions first call return another function that takes the state (lines)
- add(7)([1,2,3]) will return [1,2,3,7]
- first call is emitted by the observable (add$, delete$)
- second call is made inside the scan
*/
const override = (update) => (lines) => update;
const add = (num) => (lines) => [...lines, num];
const del = (index) => (lines) => [
  ...lines.slice(0, index),
  ...lines.slice(index + 1, lines.length)
];


const result$ = merge(
  initialValue$.pipe(map(override)), // override is called 1. time with no param
  add$.pipe(map(add)), // add is called 1. time with one param: add(num)
  delete$.pipe(map(del)), // del is called 1. time with one param: del(index)
).pipe(
  scan((lines, fn) => fn(lines), []) // depending on what observable emits the function is now emitted 2. time: fn(lines)
);

result$.subscribe(lines => console.log('lines: ', lines))

// Here the add or delete is triggered
add$.next(4);
add$.next(5);
add$.next(6);
delete$.next(0);
delete$.next(3);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Expanding the different operations on your state is very easy:

```
const deleteAll$ = new Subject();

const deleteAll = () => (lines) => []; // This function will delete all lines

// use it then inside the merge
merge(
  ...,
  deleteAll$.pipe(map(deleteAll))
);

// call it whenever you want
deleteAll$.next();
```

Changing the logic inside the functions:

```
// Before we just deleted a line by index of array
const del = (index) => (lines) => [
  ...lines.slice(0, index),
  ...lines.slice(index + 1, lines.length)
];

// Now we want to delete all numbers matching to the given param
const del = (num) => (lines) => lines.filter(line => line !== num);
```